# Oracle SQL Developer for SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is very basic question. Can we use Oracle SQL developer tool to develop things in SQL Server 2008 database?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://thinkoracle.blogspot.in/2010/09/using-oracle-sql-developer-with-ms-sql.html

Please go through this blog to step by step procedure for connecting to SQL Server database.

Hope this is helpful for you

Comment: N.B. do NOT use last "jTDS - SQL Server and Sybase JDBC driver" version (the 1.3 one is not compatible). Instead use a previous version (i.e. http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/1.2.7/jtds-1.2.7-dist.zip/download)